# Reading Max Value of Integer portion from Varchar when Some Number Portion have Different Number of Digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to read the max value out of the numeric portion of a `varchar` column in an SQL Server table. In my test below, the result is 'S999' when I need it to be 'S1000'.

```
CREATE TABLE #TemporaryTable   -- Local temporary table
(
    SerialNo varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #TemporaryTable (SerialNo)
VALUES('S999')

INSERT INTO #TemporaryTable (SerialNo)
VALUES('S1000')

SELECT MAX(SerialNo) AS MaxSerialNo
FROM #TemporaryTable
```

Returns: 'S999'

Any relatively straightforward way to get the max out of the numeric portion as though it were a number and not a string, so that the above example returns 'S1000'?

Comment: Are the strings **always** a single letter (a-z) followed by digits, or does the pattern vary? Are there ever any subsequent non-digit characters - or  more than 1 leading non-digit chars?

Comment: If it always starts with 'S': `cast(substring(SerialNo, 2, 10) as int)` There's also `cast(replace(SerialNo, 'S', '') as int)` but that doesn't assume the 'S' appears as the lead character.

Comment: It's always a single 'S' followed by the number.

Comment: @shawnt00, that worked. Thanks a ton! Who should post the answer?

Comment: Wonder why I received a downvote???

Comment: If it is always an S, why store this character at all? Just store the number and you are fine. (I don't understand the downvote either, by the way. And I hate it, when people downvote without any explanation.)

Comment: The database is just set up that way. Been like that for years so no changing it.

Comment: i didn't downvote but i think this question been answered a few times already so sometimes people don't like the lack of research effort. I also dislike the anonymous downvotes btw, but worse for answers than questions! The problem is that you don't know how to improve

Comment: Hmm. Well, I did research it. I'm OK with SQL and usually find what I need, but in this case I didn't word my search correctly or something.

Comment: To be fair, i found the stackoverflow search to be ridiculously bad, it's like it's not even trying or doing an equivalent of text like '%question%', but i guess this is off-topic too

Comment: I spent 15 minutes searching; in this day and age, it feels exhaustive. I usually find what I need in less than 5, so I presumed a question was in order. My bad, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the largest such value you can't rely on an alphabetic sort.

For ranking purposes you're really only looking to strip off the first character. So you really want everything starting at the second character onward:

```
cast(substring(SerialNo, 2, 10) as int)
```

Note that this does limit the extraction to 10 digits which is the maximum that could possible fit into an `int`. It doesn't guarantee that there won't still be an overflow nor would this fail on strings of length greater than 11.

The maximum from the group is just a normal aggregation pre-pended with the 'S':

```
'S' + max(cast(substring(SerialNo, 2, 10) as int))
```

Comment: Maybe put both options from your comment in here. And maybe a version where it adds the 'S' back in front and returns a varchar, just to be consistent with the question.